# How to import such .rds file from GEO to a classic seurat object?

Tags: r, seurat

I am a beginner in scRNA-seq analysis with seurat. I now feel "confident enough" to use the Seurat pipeline after having followed these tutorials (https://github.com/quadbiolab/scRNAseq_analysis_vignette/blob/master/Tutorial.md and https://satijalab.org/seurat/archive/v3.1/pbmc3k_tutorial.html).

I have started to analyse my own dataset, but now, I would like to annotate it using a published analysis as a reference. However, when I read the .rds file in R from the reference via readRDS(), the imported object looks very different to any classic Seurat object that I dealt with. Here is the GEO link to download the .rds file : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE138826

When I import it, and do a head(), it does not behave like a common head(). Instead, it plots hundreds of lines, in 3 rounds... I don't know how to explain it well, you have to see it yourself. typeof() says it is a list, not an S4. names() says it has "RNA" and "SCT". But when I try to extract the data by typing head(data$RNA), it shows again hundreds of lines...

I talked about this to someone, and told me to use:
CreateSeuratObject(counts = data$RNA@data, assay = "RNA", meta.data = data$RNA@varMetadata)
But here I have this output:
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

I don't know what to do with this object. Could someone help me to obtain a Seurat object from this .rds file please? What am I missing in the import from GEO ? Note that I am on macOS with a decent machine, so I don't understand why I am out of memory. Note that it takes a long amount of time to read the .rds file, so I think there is something weird with the file itself, but I am not sure...
Thanks in advance for your response,

Here is a reproducible code

```r
library(Seurat)
setwd('/Users/jchantre/Desktop/scRNA_seq_perso_analysis')
data = readRDS("Oprescu/GSE138826_regen_data.rds")

library(Seurat)
setwd('/Users/jchantre/Desktop/')
data = readRDS("GSE138826_regen_data.rds")

head(data)
typeof(data)
names(data)

typeof(data$RNA)
dim(data$RNA)
head(data$RNA)

typeof(data$SCT)
dim(data$SCT)
head(data$SCT)

seuObj = CreateSeuratObject(counts=data$RNA@data,assay="RNA",meta.data=data$RNA@varMetadata)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

works for me:

I assume you have uncompressed the file?
here are the sizes I get for the annotation and matrix files (after uncompression):

```
   531964972 Feb 14 16:42 GSE138826_regen_data.rds
  3917751779 Feb 14 16:49 GSE138826_expression_matrix.txt
```

```
> t = readRDS("~/Downloads/GSE138826_regen_data.rds")
> class(t)
[1] "list"
> names(t)
[1] "RNA" "SCT"
> class(t[[1]])
[1] "AnnotatedDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Biobase"
> class(t[[2]])
[1] "AnnotatedDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Biobase"
> sct = t[[2]]
> class(sct)
[1] "AnnotatedDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Biobase"
> sct
An object of class 'AnnotatedDataFrame'
  rowNames: Xkr4 Sox17 ... Cyp2c55 (18658 total)
  varLabels: Noninjured_AAACCCAAGTGCTCAT Noninjured_AAACCCAAGTTGTACC ... 21 DPI_TTTGTTGTCTCCCAAC (53193 total)
  varMetadata: timepoint cluster ... labelDescription
```

Apparently sct or the second object in the list contains the annotations for the matrices. The raw data (looks actually already normalized) can be downloaded/imported using the matrix.txt file from the same web-site.